# Is it possible to get to C drive from bootable ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, windows

I was configuring a window image but something went wrong and the computer says missing file in the c drive. If I make a bootable window and install it then I will lose my ready-made image. I do have bootable ubuntu. Is it possible to get to the C drive from bootable ubuntu? I will put that missing file in the C drive from the ubuntu

I commanded

```
cd \mnt\
```

but there is no c drive and when I command

```
ls -l
```

Nothing shows up

Comment: you'll have to `fdisk -l` and find the windows "C" partition, and then mount with `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` for example. you might need `ntfsfix`, or if you're using bitlocker (default on Windows 11) you'll need to do some more work for decrypting it. Google "mounting windows drive on ubuntu" for guides

Comment: @Cagri I will going to give it a shot

Comment: It should mount automatically and you should be able to access the file system from the file manager. It will not be called "C". If Windows has been suspended then you probably won't be able to make changes

Comment: @Nmath oh, what does C drive calls in Ubuntu?

Comment: It depends on what order the drive is in. Volumes in Ubuntu are labeled `sdx#` where x is a letter and # is the order of partitions. Nvme drives are labeled slightly differently. But it doesn't really matter because it should be immediately recognizable and obvious because it will have folders called Windows and Program Files.

Comment: I open Gnome-Disks, (Disks). You can tell your "C" drive by it's size compared to the USB. If there is a little triangle under it, click the triangle and it should turn to a little square. this means that your "C" drive, (probably sda), is mounted. You can then access it using Files.